# My plane keeps moving when I apply a modifier curve using a bezier curve

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

I have a plane and I have a bezier curve. When I use a curve modifier along the bezier curve my planes always moves. I need my plane to stay in the position you see in the first image and to follow the bezier curve. The origin of the plane and curve are the same but still moves.

I already tried many combinations with the origin of the curve and plane, and the position of the plane. I also already tried all the axis on the menu of the modifier and all the axis rotation of the plane. There should be a problem that I don't realized yet. Can someone download my file and examine whats wrong with it?

Before adding the modifier:

[image: Scene showing the plane location before adding the modifier]

After adding the modifier:

[image: Scene showing the plane location after adding the modifier]

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIFs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Comment: Hi, I edited your question to place the images in line as suggested by the moderator and to also add the Blend file to Blend-Exchange.  These steps make it easier for people to understand your question because they don't have to click away from it, or unpack zip file.

Comment: if you are using curves, the origins of both must be the same so that it works as expected. And you have to apply scale + rotation for both objects before.

Comment: The origins are the same. If I apply scale and rotation the plane become a mess in all axis. Without applying it at least works with the X axis